# POST and GET requests to a client API URL using Django REST

Tags: json, django, api, rest, post

I am kind of new to API.

I am working on a project where I can send POST and GET requests to different APIs. I just want to know how sort of the class in the view file should look like.

For example, I have a class that inherits generics.GenericAPIView.  How do I send a get request to a specific URL or how do I save the data using the serializer to the database with post request?

```
class ArticelViewSet(generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer_Modelserializers
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get(self, request, id=None):

        if id:
            return self.retrieve(request)

        else:
            return self.list(request)

    def post(self, request):
        return self.create(request) #return the created object
```

Comment: You normally do not write `get` or `post` objects, but you use a *router*: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/ for viewsets.

Comment: The router will, based on the url patterns and request method, automatically call the corresponding function (`retrieve`, `delete`, `list`, etc.)